# Python intersection point for two functions

Tags: python, function, numpy, intersection

I´m trying to find the intersect between the two functions. P_g for now is a constant but I want this to be flexible so I can vary it to become a sin, or linear increase.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = 100. # price at 0 catch sales local market
b1 = 0.05 # slope of price curve for species1
p = 50. # # price for species1 global

P_g = p # constant for price species1 global
P_l = d * np.exp(-b1*x) # price species1 local market
```

The most appropriate solution seemed to me:

```
P_g = ImplicitRegion[{y == p}, {x, y}]
P_l = ImplicitRegion[{y == d* np.exp(-b1*x)}, {x, y}]

solve[{k /[Element] P_g, k /[Element] P_l}, {k}]
```

Which gives me: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your call to `solve` raises the syntax error. Could you clarify what you are trying to solve?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by `scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x : d * np.exp(-b1*x) -P_g,0)`

or solve analyticalally : `x=-np.log(P_g/d)/b1.`

in both case you find : `x=13.862943611198906`